# Count distinct elements in a bag

Tags: apache-pig

Suppose I have an alias `transactions` with this data:

```
person  store  spent
A       S      3.3
A       S      4.7
B       S      1.2
B       T      3.4
```

I want to find out how many different people went to each store and how much they spent there:

```
store   visitors  revenue
S       2         9.2
T       1         3.4
```

I wish I could do it in one step:

```
stores = foreach (group transactions by store) generate
  group as store, SUM(transactions.spent) as revenue, 
  COUNT(UNIQUE(transactions.person)) as visitors;
```

but it does not look like there is such thing as `UNIQUE`.

Am I stuck with a two-step process?

```
tr1 = foreach (group transactions by (store,person)) generate
  group.store as store, SUM(spent) as revenue;
stores = foreach (group tr1 by store) generate
  group as store, COUNT(tr1) as visitors, SUM(revenue) as revenue;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches here

1) Using the Distinct builtin UDF (not the DISTINCT pig operator). Sorry, I don't have a code example and I don't know how it will perform.

2) Using a nested foreach with the DISTINCT operator
something like this:

```
stores = FOREACH (GROUP transactions BY store) {
    uniqueVisitors = DISTINCT visitors;
    GENERATE
        group AS store,
        COUNT(uniqueVisitors) AS visitors,
        SUM(revenue) AS revenue;
}
```

A nice thing about the second approach is that it shouldn't disable COMBINER:
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html#When+the+Combiner+is+Used

Answer (score 3):

Using the Distinct builtin UDF you just replace your `UNIQUE` with `org.apache.pig.builtin.Distinct` ,

```
stores = foreach (group transactions by store) generate
    group as store, SUM(transactions.spent) as revenue, 
    COUNT(org.apache.pig.builtin.Distinct(transactions.person)) as visitors;
```

Comment: Why is this UDF not listed in the builtins' [page](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#count)?

Comment: It's here https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/Distinct.html

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT should do what you are looking for.

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#DISTINCT

Comment: Are you saying that `DISTINCT` can be used on a bag?

Comment: You'll want to do the DISTINCT in a nested foreach.